# PHP DateTime objects not equal with modified Timezone

Tags: php, datetime

As of PHP 5.2.2, comparing DateTime objects using comparison operators is supported.

> 5.2.2 DateTime object comparison with the comparison operators changed to work as expected. Previously, all DateTime objects were considered equal (using ==).

My problem is that when I modify the timezone of an existing DateTime object, it is no longer equal to a DateTime object that it was equal to before changing the timezone. Weirder still is that if I call DateTime::getTimestamp() on the modified DateTime object, it will now be equal to the other DateTime object.

For example:

```
<?php

$dt = new DateTime("2016-11-08 08:27:33am -08");
$dt2 = new DateTime("2016-11-08 09:27:33am -07");

var_dump($dt == $dt2);

$dt2->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone("-08"));

var_dump($dt == $dt2);
var_dump($dt < $dt2);
var_dump($dt > $dt2);

var_dump($dt2->getTimestamp());

var_dump($dt == $dt2);
var_dump($dt < $dt2);
var_dump($dt > $dt2);
```

will produce the following output:

```
bool(true)

bool(false)
bool(false)
bool(true)

int(1478622453)

bool(true)
bool(false)
bool(false)
```

So what gives? As you can see, `$dt` and `$dt2` are equal when created, despite being in different timezones. This behaviour is expected, though. Both `$dt` and `$dt2` represent the exact same moment in time. If you call `getTimestamp()` on both of them, you will get the same number. Similarly, if you explicitly set the timezone of both DateTimes, they will be equal.

The PHP manual does state that timezone is ignored if the initialisation string contains a timezone (or is a unix timestamp):

> Note:
>   The $timezone parameter and the current timezone are ignored when the $time parameter either is a UNIX timestamp (e.g. @946684800) or specifies a timezone (e.g. 2010-01-28T15:00:00+02:00).

So I do believe that this is the cause of this seemingly irregular behaviour, but I wouldn't mind knowing why.

So, does anybody have any idea why DateTimes behave like this? How are DateTime objects *actually* compared? What is the best way to change the timezone of a DateTime object if you still need to compare it to another DateTime object?

Comment: Even creepier :-S http://pastebin.com/b8VXm5dG

Comment: Looks like a bug to me. Report it. Note that `-08` is not a real timezone. Maybe you can get better results if you used real timezones.

Comment: While offsets are indeed _not_ real timezones, PHP's documentation _does not appear_ to indicate whether it supports offsets. Were it possible for me to use exact timezones in this implementation, I would. Unfortunately, it's not possible in this case.

Code like this:
`<?php

$dt = DateTime::createFromFormat('O', "-08");
var_export($dt);`

will show the timezone as "-08:00".

Answer (score 0):

That is the [php bug](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=72338). To workaround this you could extend the DateTime class and overwrite the setTimezone method like this:

```
    class MyDateTime extends DateTime {
        public function setTimezone($timezone) {
            parent::setTimezone($timezone);
            $this->getTimestamp();
            return $this;
        }
    }
```